# Materialize js leanModal unable to reset form properties once data has given

Tags: jquery

Initially loading leanModal on clicking button (But leanModal is load when the document is ready [Data entered when the modal is shown on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npaf0.jpg))

[After form inputs are reset the form looks like how to make as first time it is loaded[3]

[Showing spaces and it is not like how it was first time loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAag2.jpg)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
        $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
            dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
            opacity: .5, // Opacity of modal background
            ready: function() { 
                $("#selectFeild").hide();
                $("#inputField").show();
            }, // Callback for Modal open
        complete: function() {
        $("#selectType").val("1");
        $("#selectFeild").hide();
        $("#inputField").show(); 
        $('form').find('input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=number], input[type=email], textarea').val('');

     } // Callback for Modal close
  });


         $('select').material_select();

      });

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
      <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="pull-right"><img src="<%=VCUtils.getContextRoot()%>images/close.png" width="20px" class=" modal-action modal-close"/></div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: center;"><h4>Join our growing network of agencies and providers</h4></div>

           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
                <div class="row" style="border-right: 1px double #eaeaea;">
                        <div class="row">
                                <img src="<%=VCUtils.getContextRoot()%>images/check.png" width="25px"/><label class="vclabel">Accountability</label>
                                <p style="color:#54aecd;">Excehange invoices and documents online -- easily and secure</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                                <img src="<%=VCUtils.getContextRoot()%>images/check.png" width="25px"/><label class="vclabel">Efficiency</label>
                                <p style="color:#54aecd;"> Start processing invoice faster with our secure customer API</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <img src="<%=VCUtils.getContextRoot()%>images/check.png" width="25px"/><label class="vclabel">Status</label>
                                <p style="color:#54aecd;">Get real-time invoice status and payment information</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>

           </div>

           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div style="margin-top: 25px; text-align: center;">
                    <form class="col s12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input id="firstName" type="text" class="validate"> <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input id="lastName" type="text" class="validate" style="font-size: 14px !important;"> <label
                                     style="font-size: 14px;" for="email">Last Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="validate"> <label
                                    for="email">Email</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select style="font-size: 14px;" id="selectType">
                                <option value="1" selected="selected">I represent a NYC Vendor</option>
                                <option value="2">I represent a NYC Agency</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                            <div id="inputField">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input id="companyName" type="text" class="validate"> <label for="firstName">Company Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>

                       <div id="selectFeild">
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select style="font-size: 14px;">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Agencies</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>

                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                                <option value="1">Actuary, NYC Office of the (NYCOA)</option>
                                <option value="2">Administrative Justice Coordinator, NYC Office of (AJC)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field  col s12">
                            <a style="width: 255.594px;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btnColor" onclick="javascript:validateFields()">Sign Up</a>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  
         </div>   
      </div>
      <!-- Thank You Model -->

       <!-- Modal Structure -->
      <div id="modal2" class="modal modalHeight">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="pull-right"><img src="<%=VCUtils.getContextRoot()%>images/close.png" width="20px" class=" modal-action modal-close"/></div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
           <p style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;">Thank you for your interest. Your request was<br/>successfully submitted.</p>
           <p style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 30px; font-weight: normal;"> We'll be in touch.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You have to reset values. I do not see any where you have resetted input fields.

Comment: I had edited code for resetting form fields within complete function but the errors and success identification css is left with and it is not loading as it was loaded first time

Comment: what is your problem now? is only problem with `<select>`?? if yes then you should use `$('select').material_select();` where you reset fields.

Comment: After form resetting the form is not looked as it was loaded for the first time (Refer image :Showing spaces and it is not like how it was first time loaded (click) )

Comment: I can see only problem in select box. For that use `$('select').material_select();` after reset.

Comment: Just i added the answer it worked for me....thanks Parth Trivedi

Comment: please check my answer. You have not made full request to your page. For that use `Ctrl+F5`. I don't see you have made any caching mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complete:

```
function() {
     //Added this line 
     location.reload(false); //you can use true or false if true it will reload      from the server if false it will reload from browser cache 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **materialize css** use

`$('select').material_select();`

to reset `Dropdownlist`